# Convert java Object into Json String

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a java class Object:

```
class TempClass {
@Expose
String errorCode
@Expose
String message
String name
String cause

TempClass(String errorCode, String message) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode
    this.message = message
  }
}
```

I am able to convert object into json using GSON jar

```
TempClass t = new TempClass("404","page not found")
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
String json = builder.create().toJson(t);
```

The JSON String I am getting is

> {
>   errorCode: "404",
>   message: "page not found"
>   }

But What I want is:

> "TempClass"{
>   errorCode: "404",
>   message: "page not found"
>   }

Or Better if there is any other sophisticated way where I can map "tempClass" (or any other property) into something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a Map, where "tempClass" is the  key and your TempClass object is the value, like this:

```
TempClass t = new TempClass("404","page not found")
Map<String, Object> map = new Hashmap<String, Object> ();
map.put("tempClass", t);
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
String json = builder.create().toJson(map);
```

This is a sort of easy and fast way to achieve what you need due to Maps are parsed out-of-the-box by Gson, but be careful: in case you have more properties like this one, it could be better to create a new class for that